# Showing the law of trichotomy through a continuous function without a fix point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Unfortunately this exercise shatters me:

> Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x \in I$. Show that either $f(x) > x$ for all $x \in I$ or $f(x) <x$ for all $x \in I$

**My problems**: When I first looked at this exercise I thought it to be a joke, then I realized that I cannot proof it. By the [law of trichotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)/%22law%20of%20trichotomy%22) a real number is either positive, negative or zero. Thus the statement becomes trivial.

However I realized that we did never proof trichotomy in class and therefore this exercise becomes much harder to me, in fact so hard that I don't even know what to do anymore.

**My (failed) attempt**: Of course I have to work with $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ being a continuous function, there is no other way I could start this exercise in my opinion. In fact $f$ is continuous on $I$ so I can say $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in I \text{ with } |x-x_0| < \delta \text{ it follows that } |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon $$
At least I have the the $\forall x \in I$ statement already satisfied by the definition of continuity, but I don't see how to proceed from here. I could try to write $$f(x) = f(x)-f(x_0) + f(x_0) > -\epsilon + f(x_0) $$
but I don't see how this should help and how to continue from here. I'd appreciate hints to clear my vision or the next successful step in the argument. How do I apply the criteria $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x \in I$ without using trichotomy? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $I$ is an interval then

$$
I = f_{-1}(-\infty,x) \cup f_{-1}(x, \infty)
$$
so, since $f$ is continuous both these disjoint components of its inverse image are open. but this contradicts the connectedness of $I$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DavidHolden, I am afraid I will have to wait for more elementary ones, since words like connectedness and openness have no meaning (so far) to me.

Answer (score 0):

suppose for $a \lt b \in I$ we have $f(a) \lt 0$ and $f(b) \gt 0$

define $a' = \sup\{x \in [a,b]: g(x) \lt 0\}$ and consider $f(a')$

Comment: why is the first line true? we have arbitrary $a<b$ in our interval and then it should follow that $f(a)< 0$ and $f(b) > 0$ ?